# Backbone Collection URL is Undefined

Tags: backbone.js

trying to pass the url to the fetchFromURL function but URL is undefined when loggin it. NO IDEA why this is happening!!

```
class Device extends Backbone.Model

class Devices extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Device
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage 'devices'
    url: "http://192.168.2.17:8030/profile/RestProfile.svc/GetDeviceList/"
    fetchFromURL: =>
        collection = @
        console.log @url

getView = =>
    devices = new Devices
    devices.fetch()
    devices.fetchFromURL()
```

Comment: Very odd, at a quick glance the code looks fine. Maybe a coffeescript indentation issue?

Comment: I think it was an issue with indentation or something, removed all the spaces and re indented it and it worked.. Strange

Comment: yeah, the joys of meaningful whitespace. Glad it worked out.